# How to make binary variables and conditional constraints with CVXPY in Python

Tags: python, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem to size an off grid hybrid renewable energy system. The code works and I get some results, but the problem is that the battery is charging and discharging at the same time. I want to avoid this in the constraints, but do not know how to make a condtional constraint thats says, when charging is positive, discharging have to be negative and vice versa.

[image]

Here are the parameters

```py
"""
Parameters for optimization
c_0: weigth of load curtailment
c_wt: Cost of wind turbine
c_pv: cost of PV
p_N: Charge/discharge capacity
C_B: Max capacity battery
C_B_low: Minimum capacity battery
C_0: Start capacity battery
n_d: Discharge efficiency
n_c: Charge efficiency
"""
params = {'c_0': 100,
          'c_wt': 1000,
          'c_pv': 500,
          'p_N': 10000,
          'C_B':45000,
          'C_B_low':9000,
          'C_0':25000,
          'n_d':0.9,
          'n_c':0.95}
```

Here is the optimization function

```py
 ###Length, weight and cost variables. Cost and weight are just assumptions
    n = len(p_l)
    
    ###Optimization variables
    s_pvs = cp.Variable(1, integer = True,)
    s_pvsw = cp.Variable(1, integer = True)
    s_pvse = cp.Variable(1, integer = True)
    s_wt = cp.Variable(1, integer = True)
    
    #Charging
    p_c = cp.Variable(n)
    #Discharging
    p_d = cp.Variable(n)
    #State of charge
    SOC = cp.Variable(n)
    
    #Load curtail
    p_lcurt = cp.Variable(n)

    
    ###Objective function 
    obj = cp.sum(params["c_0"]*p_lcurt + params["c_wt"]*s_wt + params["c_pv"]*(s_pvs + s_pvsw + s_pvse))
    
    ###Constraints
    constraints = [params["p_N"] >= p_c, p_c >= 0,
                   
                   params["p_N"] >= p_d, p_d >= 0,
                   
                   s_pvs >= 0, s_pvsw >= 0, s_pvse >= 0, 
                   
                   s_wt >= 0, p_lcurt >= 0, 
                   
                   SOC >= params["C_B_low"], SOC <= params["C_B"],
                   
                   SOC[0] == params["C_0"] + p_c[0]*params["n_c"] - p_d[0]/params["n_d"],
                   
                   SOC[1:] == SOC[:-1] + p_c[1:]*params["n_c"] - p_d[1:]/params["n_d"],
                  
                   s_pvs*p_pvs + s_pvse*p_pvse + s_pvsw*p_pvsw + s_wt*p_wt
                   - p_l + p_lcurt - p_c + p_d == 0]
    
    problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints)
    problem.solve(solver = cp.GLPK_MI, verbose = True)
    
    
    print("s_pvsw:",s_pvsw.value,"s_pvse:",s_pvse.value,"s_pvs:", s_pvs.value,"s_wt:",
          s_wt.value,"Problem solution", problem.value)
        
    
    return s_pvsw.value, s_pvse.value, s_pvs.value, s_wt.value, SOC.value, p_lcurt.value, p_d.value, p_c.value
```

I have tried to make an if statement in the constraints, but this was not possible due to syntax error

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy

Comment: Modeling of "if" conditions must take place through some mixed-integer model with indicator variables. Maybe one of this section will be useful to you: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html

Comment: Consider deleting and re-posting at Operations Research SE